# Getting git server on VM

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, server

I'm using Vagrant&VirtualBox to work with ubuntu machine.
Now, I want to make this machine as a server through commands in the terminal.
I am using this machine on a Windows based PC, and I want to make a git project on the Windows PC and push it to the server that sits on the Virtual machine.
I saw this guides:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server
And I did all the steps but got stuck in the step of configuring the URL for the remote. As I said my remote server sits on the Ubuntu VM that I created using Vagrant. 
I made the address like this:
vagrant@127.0.0.1:/opt/git/project.git
(I assume there is a problem in this address)
but when I try to push I get errors like:

fatal: 'vagrant@127.0.0.1/opt/git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I already copied the id_rsa.pub that i generated from Windows into the .ssh library and copied it to authorized_keys. 
What is the problem? (might be lots of them..)

Comment: I'm confused about why pushing to a Vagrant VM would be helpful. What are you actually trying to accomplish? There is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with address, you cannot access localhost from different machine. binding of repository with machine's ip/hostname should be there. Let's say your local machine and VM are on 192.168.x.y series (considering network bridge). Then you can access without any error. Or you can try [GitStack](http://gitstack.com/)
to host git server on windows machine and access it using any git client.